# Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'AppStream': Cannot prepare internal mirrorlist |Centos

Tags: linux, centos

I got issue in centos
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'AppStream': Cannot prepare internal mirrorlist |Centos

try below steps:

Please mentions your issue messages and solution too

my Solution to this issue is
Solution.1

Go to /etc/yum.repos.d/

cd /etc/yum.repos.d/

Run

sudo sed -i 's/mirrorlist/#mirrorlist/g' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-*
sudo sed -i 's|#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org|baseurl=http://vault.centos.org|g' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-*
sudo yum update -y

i was still getting error below

CentOS Linux 8 - AppStream                                                              111  B/s |  38  B     00:00
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'appstream': Cannot prepare internal mirrorlist: No URLs in mirrorlist

Solution worked.

## sed -i 's/mirrorlist/#mirrorlist/g' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-*

## sed -i 's|#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org|baseurl=http://vault.centos.org|g' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-*

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

I send the commands and now it is working:

```bash
sed -i 's/mirrorlist/#mirrorlist/g' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-*
sed -i 's|#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org|baseurl=http://vault.centos.org|g' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-*
```

Thanks so much.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34609313)